# Cannot start resourcemanager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

getting following error while starting resource manager in new stable release.

```
2013-10-17 10:01:51,230 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping ResourceManager metrics system...
2013-10-17 10:01:51,230 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system stopped.
2013-10-17 10:01:51,231 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2013-10-17 10:01:51,232 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.getResourceCalculator(CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.reinitialize(CapacityScheduler.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1744)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
    ... 6 more
2013-10-17 10:01:51,239 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at node1/192.168.147.101
```

Please help whats the issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the property

```
 <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
```

to this value

```
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator</value>
```

seems to do the trick for Hadoop 2.2.0 and Hadoop 2.3.0. Reference [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/ea8lW05jQwh4sb9uMqMf).